# ECMAScript 6 - что за конструкция?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript

Читал статью про воркеры, и нашёл такую конструкцию в примере, хотел узнать что это за "search:"

```
var n = 1;
search: while (true) {
  n += 1;
  for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 1)
    if (n % i == 0)
     continue search;
  // found a prime!
  postMessage(n);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Могу ошибаться, но судя по всему это метка, к которой происходит переход в случае, если выполняется условие

```
if (n % i == 0)
```

то есть в отличие от обычного **continue** происходит перехолд не на следующую итерацию цикла **for**, а на гораздо более раннюю позицию, к началу цикла **while**. Это такой "урезанный" аналог goto в языках типа С++б Basic, Pascal или C#. При этом, насколько помню, аналогичные "урезанные" **goto** есть в Java

Comment: Вы не ошибаетесь - это она и есть: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label